# Moment generating function of a piecewise function

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

I am struggling like crazy with question b.

[image: question]

Here is what I have come up with:

[image: ans2]

But if I then test $M_X'(0)$, I don't get the expected value I calculated in part a:

[image: part a]

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be dividing by $t$ when doing the integrals in $(b)$?

Comment: @Semiclassical lol, thanks I am such a dofus ...